# OS X Mavericks "Share Internet from Ethernet to Wi-Fi" fails after a period of time

Tags: macos, networking, wireless-networking, internet-sharing

When the computer first boots up, I can share Internet from Ethernet to Wi-Fi without a problem. But after a few days, it starts to malfunction. I notice that when the Wi-Fi is shared, in the place of the Wi-Fi signal icon, there will be an icon with an arrow up. Now when I try to enable Wi-Fi sharing, I notice that the icon changes to that arrow up icon, but then it immediately changes to the Wi-Fi signal icon and my Wi-Fi is connects to another nearby Wi-Fi network. I wonder if something is wrong here? Or if Mavericks only allows me to share Internet to Wi-Fi if no other Wi-Fi network is around (???)

Comment: Is the problem that the Mac doing Internet Sharing doesn't get back into software AP mode after sleep/wake?

Comment: I think so. I put it to sleep at the end of the day.